# How can i calculate a linear system using Matrix on Android?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, opengl-es, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a linear system on Android platform to perform some image processing. (OpenGL or Java Matrix).
Currently i have a 4x4 matrix and 4x1 vector represented as Matrix4f and Float4f respectively.
I want to divide them and save the output vector.
I need to use a Matrix because later i'll draw on the device screen a picture transformed by a matrix i'll generate from that vector result.
I could't find how to multiply the two on Android.
Already saw answers suggesting using a third party library ( JScience library ), but i prefer not to do so, only as a last resort.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "divide them"?

Comment: Whatever unclear "divide them" means: if you have a 4x4 matrix and 4x1 vector and want multiply them, the simplest way is just write short and simple function that will multiply 4x4 matrix and 4x1 vector.

Comment: Hi, maybe i was unclear. i'm looking the Java equilevent for the Matlab command x = A\ B; where A is 4x4 matrix and B is 4x1 matrix.